# Can I use a UPS as a Voltage Stabilizer for 32 or 42 inch LED TV?

Tags: electrical, led, television

I need a voltage stabilizer for 32 inch or 42 inch LED TV. Can I use a UPS for this?

I'm expecting the Voltage control when the input power is beyond 270V or 290V and to produce output 240V range.

- Minimum Input Power (V)  167 V
- Maximum Input Power (V)  290 V
- Minimum Output Power (V) 200 V
- Maximum Output Power (V) 240
- Minimum Frequency (Hz)   50
- Other Power Features:

  - High Voltage Cut-off or Control: 290 V Input (240 V Output),
  - Capacity 3 Amps,
  - 120 - 290 V Input Voltage Range

Comment: @DownVoter: Please clarify the usage of UPS in this case. As I'm having UPS at my home

Comment: -1 because this looks like it's off topic, and if I vote to close it's binding. It's approaching a product recommendation, product specific advice, electrical engineering, and small appliances. All either off topic for this site or more relevant for another site that I'm pretty sure would not accept a migration.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about purchasing a product.  It probably should be migrated to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @wallyk FYI electronics SE [does not want consumer electronics questions *or* shopping questions](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need a voltage stabilizer? Generally, with modern electronics, the power supply itself will filter out most line noise you're likely to encounter on reasonably modern wiring.

(I have seen an Uninterruptable Power Supply pressed into service as a line conditioner, in an old hotel where line voltage could suddenly drop well below 90VAC. So it's possible. However, I believe selecting the correct model of UPS would be important, but I can't advise what models or marketing keywords to look for.)

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, yes - just look for line conditioning as a feature. Our municipal electric supply is notoriously bad with voltage fluctuations, so I have the vast majority of my electronics running through either a UPS or a line conditioner.

Unless your intention is to have a battery back-up, you might be able to get a dedicated line conditioner with automatic voltage regulation cheaper than an uninterruptable power supply of the same usable wattage.  As far as sizing, Wattage is equal to voltage times amperage - in your case you would want at something rated for a draw of at least 660 watts (220v * 3A).